# Sending http traffic to HTTPS for multiple domains

Tags: javascript, php

I have this `index.php` file redirecting `http` traffic to the `https` side of the server.  In it has this code:

```
<?php
        echo "<script> location.href='https://domain1.com'; </script>";
        exit;
?>
```

It used to work, when I have one domain on the server.  Now I have multiple:

```
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
etc...
```

How do I tell the script to redirect to `https` for the respective domains, and not autoroute always to `domain1.com`?

thanks!

Update 1:  For those who are asking about folders.  the `http` site is `/var/www/html` and the `https` site is `/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/`.  The second one is the real site.

Comment: Can you access FTP? When you use Apache maybe you can do this with .htaccess

Comment: How does this not lead to a never-ending loop?

Comment: idk.  I found this one  on a website, and it works great.  I believe that the difference is http is /var/www/html and https is /var/www/vhost/site.  the html folder is really nothing but a place holder.

Comment: Would be a lot cleaner to do this with `.htaccess` on server. Next best would be do php redirect by checking protocol in $_SERVER global.  Worst approach is using javascript

Comment: You don't need to do this in your app in my opinion. Do it either at the server level (.htaccess if Apache, etc) or even higher via a service like Cloudflare for free.

Comment: If you've got multiple domains - why not do it in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` directives in *httpd-vhosts.conf* ?

Comment: I'm open for solutions.  how do I do this?

Comment: You absolutely do not want to be doing this via PHP echoing JavaScript. You need to do this with Apache, which you could do by creating a `.htaccess` file for the website and writing the redirect in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already configuring the domains in Apache's *httpd-vhosts.conf* file, you can just set the `<VirtualHost>` on port 80 to redirect to the relevant https domain.

For instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
Redirect / https://www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com

SSLEngine On
... and so on ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain2.com
Redirect / https://www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain2.com

SSLEngine On
... and so on ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Next best option would be to do it via .htaccess at the document root (in your case `/var/www/html`) - something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If all else fails you can do it with an http header redirect in PHP using the `header()` function - like so:

```
<?php
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
    header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die();
}
```

This would be `/var/www/html/index.php` for your example.

---

**Note:** Since you're using different docroots for HTTP and HTTPS you can leave out the HTTPS checks; you'll only ever hit `/var/www/html` under HTTP anyway.

Comment: the third one worked like a charm (had to change http: to https: in the header line).  I realize that the other two are better....I'll start seeing what to do to make them work.  until then.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @arcee123 - heh well spotted on the *deliberate* typo (\*coughs\* yeah) - fixed.